# Curl to Javascript

Tags: javascript, curl

I am making a Chrome Extension that talks to a website via an api. I want it to pass information about a current tab to my website via a cors request.

I have a POST api request already working. It looks like this:

```
...
var url = "https://webiste.com/api/v1/users/sendInfo"
...
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({user_name:user_name, password:password, info:info}));
```

Its corresponding curl statement is something like this:

```
curl -X POST https://website.com/api/v1/users/sendInfo -d '{ username:"username", password:"password", info: "Lot's of info" }' --header "Content-type: application/json
```

But, this is not as secure as we want. I was told to mirror the curl command below:

```
curl --basic -u username:password <request url> -d '{ "info": "Lot's of info" }'
```

But, one cannot just write curl into javascript.
If someone could either supply javascript that acts like this curl statement or explain exactly what is going on in that basic option of the curl script I think that I could progress from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `curl` command is setting a [basic `Authorization` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). This can be done in JavaScript like

```
var url = "https://webiste.com/api/v1/users/sendInfo",
    username = "...",
    password = "...";
xhr.open('POST', url, true, username, password);
xhr.send(...);
```

This encodes the username/password using base 64, and sets the `Authorization` header.

---

**Edit** As arcyqwerty mentioned, this is no more *secure* than sending username/password in the request body JSON. The advantage of using the basic authentication approach is that it's a standard way of specifying user credentials which integrates well with many back-ends. If you need security, make sure to send your data over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

`curl` is the `curl` binary which fetches URLs.

`--basic` tells `curl` to use "[HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)"

`-u username:password` tells `curl` supply a given username/password for the authentication.  This authentication information is base64 *encoded* in the request.  Note the emphasis on *encoded* which is different from *encrypted*.  HTTP basic auth is **not** secure (although it can be made more secure by using an HTTPS channel)

`-d` tells `curl` to send the following as the data for the request

You may be able to specify HTTP basic authentication in your request by making the request to `https://username:password@website.com/api/v1/users/sendInfo`